# Is "migrationProgress" really a getter of NSMigrationManager?

Tags: ios, core-data, key-value-observing

I just got core data migration working via NSMigrationManager. According to Apple doc:

> migrationProgress Returns a number from 0 to 1 that indicates the
>   proportion of completeness of the migration.
>
> - (float)migrationProgress
>
> Return Value A number from 0 to 1 that indicates the proportion of completeness of the migration. If a
>   migration is not taking place, returns 1.
>
> Special Considerations You can observe this value using key-value
>   observing.

I used KVO getting notified the % of migration progress, but I am wondering if "migrationProgress" really is a getter?
If it is, why didn't Apple document it as a "readonly" property, to make it clear for developer to use?

Comment: Yes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430180/how-to-show-migration-progress-of-nsmigrationmanager-in-a-uilabel

Comment: This enhancement request should interest you: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5830444276776960 . And that method is a readonly accessor, it's just not declared as a property. If you put in a bug on it now, it will probably get fixed as they change things for Swift.

Comment: Wow...you get a pair of quick hands, @quellish !!!

Comment: If you duplicate that radar, it's more likely to get addressed soon ;) Using NSProgress for this would have a lot of advantages.

Comment: How did you use it with NSMigrationManager? Subclassing NSMigrationManager, then compose a NSProgress property inside the sub-NSMigrationManager ?